# Як перекласти "Изложите весь список, пожалуйста"?

Tags: переклад

Відомо, що "излагать" - це "викладати". Варіант "Викладьте весь список, будь ласка" навряд чи підходить через відсутність довершеної форми наказового способу у цьому дієслові.

Comment: Ukrainian.SE — це не перекладацький сайт. Автор запитання має продемонструвати свою спробу відповісти на запитання, пояснити своїми словами текст іноземною мовою, а також пояснити, чим запропоновані у словниках чи інших джерелах варіанти перекладу вас не задовольнили.

Comment: У «викласти» (доконаного виду) є наказовий спосіб — це «[ви́кладіть](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=викласти)». Іще «ви́голосіть» (рос. «огласите»), а також «прочитайте», «зачитайте», «подайте», «наведіть».

Comment: @Kosarar, дякую, що уточнили запитання. Згоден, що його тепер можна перевідкрити. Менше з тим, свій мінус я не зніму, бо таки не наведено спробу самостійно знайти відповідь в Інтернеті. Будь ласка, наступним разом завжди робіть таку спробу, тоді запитання будуть цікавішими.

Comment: @Sasha як на мене, формула "Прошу `особа у знахідному відмінку` `інфінітив` ... " - менше ріже око, коли необхідно передати ідею наказового способу в цьому випадку

Comment: Якщо це цитата з "Операції И" то там було "Огласите..."

Comment: Дякую, Сашо. «ви́голосіть», «наведіть» дуже добре вписуються у відповідь. Дякую також Artemix♦ - але це я творчо перероблюю свої знання.

Comment: Було б непогано сформулювати відповідь.

Comment: Викладіть весь список. 
Виголосіть весь список.

Comment: Як на мене, то або "оголосіть весь список", або "перелічіть всі варіанти"

Answer (score 2):

> <sup>Російсько-український словник сталих виразів ¬ *[излагать](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile.php?transfer=folders/i/izlagatm.html)*
>
>   └ [Іван Вирган](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [Марія Пилинська](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0)</sup>
>   **Излагать, изложить в письменной форме, письменно.**
>
> Викладати, викласти на письмі (письмом, у письмовій формі); списувати, списати що.

---

> <sup>Російсько-український словник сталих словосполучень ¬ *[и](http://ros-ukr-idioms.wikidot.com/i)*
>
>   └ [Сергій Головащук](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)</sup>
>   **излагать, изложить мнение** • викладати, викласти думку.
>   **излагать, изложить просьбу** • викладати, викласти прохання.
>   **излагать, изложить суть вопроса** • викладати, викласти суть питання.

[Викладати](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) — дієслово недоконаного виду
[Викласти](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) — дієслово доконаного виду

---

**Прошу викласти весь список.**

Comment: Думаю калькувати не потрібно. При перекладі потрібно дивитися не на слова окремо, а на ціле речення. Відповідно традиції української мови в цьому реченні бажано використати слово "надайте".